# good syntax for ruby scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, named-scope

I just wanna know if there is a way of doing this :

I want an "invited" method for my user class to create a list of user(s) that have their referral_code equals to the self.confirmation_token

I tried a lot of things and the last thing was almost good I know it, but I have a syntax error ...

```
scope :invited, -> {|u| where("referral_code = ?", confirmation_token)}
```

ofc by this I mean that I want to iterate on every user in the database (|u|)

Comment: try this `scope :invited, -> {where("referral_code = confirmation_token")}`

Answer (score 1):

you could write:

```
scope :invited, ->(token) { where("referral_code = ?", token) }
```

and then: `User.ivited(some_token)`, but if you need users who have the same `referral_code` and `confirmation_token` fields, you could write:

```
scope :invited, -> { where "referral_code = confirmation_token" }
```

according to your comment (`I need users who have the same referral_code than the confirmation_token of the user caller of the method invited`),  you could write:

```
def invited
  where "referral_code = ?", confirmation_token
end
```

and then: `User.last.invited`

Comment: ["Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes."](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) so `def self.invited(token) ...` would be the recommended option.

Comment: Thank you ! But I need users who have the same referral_code than the  confirmation_token of the user caller of the method invited